# Does a tool exist which can take a LaTeX equation and convert it to a format suitable for evaluation in Wolfram's Mathematica?

Tags: equations, wolfram-mathematica

I use LaTeX to type up my homework, but as I work I often need to pop things into *Mathematica* (or manually type them in, or manually use my [TI-89](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI-89_series), etc.).

Currently, I've been manually translating things like `\frac{a}{b}` into (a/b) for *Mathematica*'s consumption... is there a tool out there which does this automagically?

Comment: I'm also interested in whether proposed solutions work for Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Is there a similar capability for Maple? All I can find in the documentation is the reverse - LateX export.

Comment: @rogerl: That deserves a separate question, I think.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Mathematica can do this itself: `ToExpression["\\frac{a}{b}", TeXForm]`.

The mathematica frontend will automatically perform the necessary doubling of the backslashes so long as you are pasting into a string (ie, put the cursor between quotes `""` before pasting)

You didn't ask, but you can also go the other way mathematica->Tex: `TeXForm[a/b]` gives `\frac{a}{b}`.

You can also use a mixture of TeX and mathematica in a file `document.mtex` and use the mathematica `Splice["document.mtex"]` command to replace `<*`, `*>` delimited mathematica input by TeXForm mathematica output. Eg:

```
The derivative of $x^x$ is $<*D[x^x,x]*>$.
```

Splices to:

```
The derivative of $x^x$ is $x^x (\log (x)+1)$.
```

Comment: Too bad it doesn't work with intergals. Thanks +1 and checkmark.

Comment: It ***does*** work with integrals; try 'ToExpression["\\int \\sin(\\sin(x)) \\, dx", TeXForm]'

Comment: Is there a way to do this by reading a text file containing the expression, rather than copy-pasting?